# How to stream real time data using Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to observer changes from server in my android app.
So I'm  using this interface for open stream with server.

```
public interface Service {
 @GET("/n/{id}/streaming")
void streamThreads(@Path("name_space_id") String Id, @QueryMap Map<String, String> options,@Query("exclude_types") String type, Callback<Object> callback);
}
```

and this is my method where I can get response in my activity

```
  server.streamThreads(accountInfo.getId(), map, "thread", new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Object o, Response response) {
            String json = (String) o;
            Log.i(TAG,json);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Response r = error.getResponse();
            if (r != null)
                Log.e(TAG, "error: " + r.getReason());
        }
    });
```

So I tested method in web browser and life stream works.
But response comes in my mobile app every 30 minutes. I'm using one activity and call method onCreate().

Thanks

Comment: I do not know, if this is possible with an Rest-API and Retrofit. I think this is only for Send Request -> Get Response kind of connections. Nothing like streaming. For streaming I would use something like WebSockets. But I'm not an expert.

Comment: What kind of application is this? In many cases, Google Cloud Messaging is required to avoid draining the battery.

Comment: this is mail application.But server now doesn't support Google Cloud messaging.I wrote to support they said to use open stream technology.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit provides an @Streaming annotation.
The unread byteStream can then be obtained from the raw OkHttp ResponseBody.